# React native switch case statement

Tags: react-native, switch-statement

Beginning student react native who has question regarding switch statement.

On the website reactnative.dev there is an example with an alert message:

```js
 checkSwitch=(param)=>{

    switch(param) {
      case '1':
        this.ONE();
        break;   
      case '2':
        this.TWO();
        break;
      case '3':
        this.THREE();
        break;
      case '4':
        this.FOUR();
        break;
      default:
        Alert.alert(param);
      }
  }

  ONE=()=>{
    Alert.alert("ONE");
  }

  TWO=()=>{
    Alert.alert("TWO");
  }

  THREE=()=>{
    Alert.alert("THREE");
  }

  FOUR=()=>{
    Alert.alert("FOUR");
  }
```

Instead of an alert message, I want a third box with the result in function of the input.

My code (which doesn't work):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      TextInput_Data : ''
    }
  }

  checkSwitch=(param)=>{

    switch(param) {

      case '1':
        return "Z";
         
      case '2':
        return "Y";
        break;

      case '3':
        return "X";
        break;

      default:
        Alert.alert("NUMBER NOT FOUND");        
      }
  }


  render() {

    return (

      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter Value Here"
          onChangeText={data => this.setState({ TextInput_Data: data })}
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          keyboardType = {"numeric"}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.checkSwitch.bind(this, this.state.TextInput_Data)} activeOpacity={0.6} style={styles.button} >
 
          <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> GET RESULT </Text>

        </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.textOutputStyle}> outcome = return X, Y or Z </Text>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do: if "1" is entered, the outcome ("Z) should be displayed in the third box. Obviously, if entered "2", the outcome should be "Y" and if entered "3", it should be "X".

Every suggestion is welcome (edited to clarify my question)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but if I understood correctly, you want to show the actual input result in the alert box. For this you could change your default case to display whatever you pass as an argument to that switch case.

checkSwitch=(param)=>{

```
switch(param) {

  case '1':
    return "Z";
     
  case '2':
    this.TWO();
    break;

  default:
    Alert.alert(param);
  }

}
```

If this is not the case, try to explain an issue in a better way, also put the link of an example you're trying to follow.